# transition matrix for urn model

Tags: probability, econometrics, model, markov-process, transition-matrix

**There are slides regrading to urn model**

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have two questions

1. if  a Species A dies and a Species A is born, the original text says the probability is 0.4*0.4, but since a Species A has died , only one Species A is left, shouldn't the probability for a new bornspecies A be (2-1)/(5-1)=1/4=0.25?
2. I don't understand what the row vector means? since it has 6 components, does it mean it has 6 individuals or 6 species?

Answer (score 1):

1. It appears that they can give birth and die simultaneously - only way I can explain the model.
2. The reason for 6 is that the number of either can be 0,1,2,3,4, or 5 (6 possibilities).